# Exception while extending JavaFX LineChart

Tags: java, javafx, properties, javafx-2, linechart

I would like to extend JavaFX `LineChart` to add some functionalities (give access to the legend so it can be customized, adding visible bounds, etc.). I've created an `EnhancedLineChart` class an declared an instance on my FXML file but it returns an exception:

> Caused by: com.sun.javafx.fxml.PropertyNotFoundException: Property "xAxis" does not exist or is read-only.

Here is my **class**:

```
package com.ratp.oam.widgets.graph;

import com.sun.javafx.charts.Legend;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.chart.Axis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;

public class EnhancedLineChart extends LineChart<Number, Number> {
    public EnhancedLineChart() {
        super(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
    }

    public EnhancedLineChart(final NumberAxis xAxis, final NumberAxis yAxis) {
        super(xAxis, yAxis);
    }

    public EnhancedLineChart(final NumberAxis xAxis, final NumberAxis yAxis,
            ObservableList<Series<Number, Number>> data) {
        super(xAxis, yAxis, data);
    }

    @Override
    public Axis<Number> getXAxis() {
        return super.getXAxis();
    }

    @Override
    public Axis<Number> getYAxis() {
        return super.getYAxis();
    }

    /**
     * Fournit la légende du graphique telle qu'elle a été implémentée dans la
     * classe {@link LineChart}.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Legend legend() {
        return (Legend) super.getLegend();
    }
}
```

and the **FXML file** where my component is instantiated (DataGraph.fxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.ratp.oam.widgets.graph.EnhancedLineChart?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.HBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" spacing="3">
    <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" styleClass="scroll-pane">
        <fx:define>
            <EnhancedLineChart fx:id="analogicalChart" createSymbols="false" animated="false" prefHeight="350">
                <padding>
                    <Insets topRightBottomLeft="0" />
                </padding>

                <xAxis>
                    <NumberAxis fx:id="analogicalXAxis" animated="false" side="BOTTOM" forceZeroInRange="false" autoRanging="false" />
                </xAxis>

                <yAxis>
                    <NumberAxis animated="false" side="LEFT" forceZeroInRange="false" autoRanging="false" />
                </yAxis>
            </EnhancedLineChart>
        </fx:define>

        <VBox fx:id="graphBox">
            <VBox fx:id="logicalPane" />
        </VBox>
    </ScrollPane>
</fx:root>
```

How could I solve my problem?

**Nota Bene**

- I've checked package import on my FXML file.
- I get the same result when I delete the 2 overridden methods.

Comment: [mcve] please .. and which fx version are you _really_ using? fx2 is far from current ;)

Comment: What is missing please? (JavaFX 2.2)

Comment: something I can throw into my IDE, compile and run .. without having to do anything else

Comment: It is better for you if I show the complete stack trace?

Comment: ohh, couldn't believe it, sry .. that's really old  - why do you stick to such an outdated version? Probably hard to find anybody who's willing or even able to reproduce with that ..

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use JavaFX 8... This is a professional software which has to run on Windows XP machines, and [it is not fully supported on it](https://www.java.com/fr/download/faq/winxp.xml).

Comment: the complete stacktrace definitely is needed - though it doesn't help in reproducing the problem. Anyway, with fx2, I'm out .. that's too oldish for me, completely unsupported as of now. If you really want to invest your time on custom charts, start with fx11+ (fx14 is going out in a couple of weeks)

Comment: wow .. what a combination, unsupported OS and unsupported fx .. good luck!

Comment: Welcome to the software industry ;)

Comment: *hehe .. am here since decades <g> Seriously: do you really want fx, then? Maybe Swing with a third-party charting framework might be the better option?

Comment: Swing wouldn't be a problem but my company wants to "update" their Java softwares by switching to JavaFX (more convenient syntax, file architecture, etc.). My software is an exception, on the average they use newer versions of JavaFX.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've found the solution by looking at the `LineChart` class. If I want to use `xAxis`, `yAxis` and `data` in my FXML file, I need to place the `@NamedArg` annotation before constructor arguments, so the instances can be called by the FXML loader. The result looks like this:

```
package com.ratp.oam.widgets.graph;

import com.sun.javafx.charts.Legend;

import javafx.beans.NamedArg;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;

public class EnhancedLineChart extends LineChart<Number, Number> {
    public EnhancedLineChart(@NamedArg("xAxis") NumberAxis xAxis, @NamedArg("yAxis") NumberAxis yAxis) {
        super(xAxis, yAxis);
    }

    public EnhancedLineChart(@NamedArg("xAxis") NumberAxis xAxis, @NamedArg("yAxis") NumberAxis yAxis, @NamedArg("data") ObservableList<Series<Number, Number>> data) {
        super(xAxis, yAxis, data);
    }

    /**
     * Fournit la légende du graphique telle qu'elle a été implémentée dans la
     * classe {@link LineChart}.
     */
    public Legend legend() {
        return (Legend) super.getLegend();
    }
}
```